# How to make a view refresh after flipView is dismissed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a mapView with different pins on it. I also have a flipView where you can toggle the pins on or off.

My problem Is that when the filpView is dismissed the function to add the pins isn't run again so the same pins stay on the map.

Is there a way to run the viewDidLoad function again or it there a better way to change the pins?

Here is my [Code](http://pastebin.com/qDbAkpL0) for both views.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add your Pins and dispatch localMap method in `viewWillAppear:` method like bellow

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

      NSArray *ann = [yourMapView annotations];
     [yourMapView removeAnnotations:ann];
     [self addPins]; 
     //force the map to start on the main queue
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{[self localMap];});
}
```

Comment: Thanks That has worked. but no I see a floor in my logic. The method runs and correctly doesnt add the pins that are filtered off but the pins are still there as I havent removed them. Do you know Of a way that I can clear all the old pins off before I add pin new pins?

Comment: yes see my edited answer.. just remove all Annotation from mapview.. see